# docker daemon wont monitor port on windows and error if alter json

Tags: docker

How can I correctly get the docker daemon to monitor port 2375?

On my windows machine, the docker command works in bash, but dockerd doesn't :

```
docker info
Client:
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  app: Docker Application (Docker Inc., v0.8.0)
  buildx: Build with BuildKit (Docker Inc., v0.3.1-tp-docker)

dockerd
'dockerd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I need the daemon to monitor localhost:2375.

I checked this box 7 restarted in Docker desktop:
[image]

Also, if I try to change this file in Docker desktop, Docker will not restart:

[image]

I change the file in this prompt, hit apply, and restart the app:

[image]

Then I get an error, and have to restore to factory default:

```
Docker.Core.Backend.BackendException:
Failed to start
   at Docker.Core.Pipe.NamedPipeClient.<TrySendAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Docker.Core.Pipe.NamedPipeClient.Send(String action, Object[] parameters)
   at Docker.Actions.<RestartDaemon>b__37_0()
   at Docker.ApiServices.TaskQueuing.TaskQueue.<>c__DisplayClass18_0.<.ctor>b__1()

  Docker.Core.DockerException:
  Failed to start
     at Docker.Backend.ContainerEngine.Linux.DoStart(Settings settings, String daemonOptions, Credential credential)
     at Docker.Backend.ContainerEngine.Linux.Restart(Settings settings, String daemonOptions, Credential credential)
     at Docker.Backend.BackendNamedPipeServer.<Run>b__8_3(Object[] args)
     at Docker.Core.Pipe.NamedPipeServer.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.<Register>b__0(Object[] parameters)
     at Docker.Core.Pipe.NamedPipeServer.RunAction(String action, Object[] parameters)
```

Comment: Don't ever try to access Docker this way: anyone who can access the socket can run any `docker` command they want, including running a container with administrator-level privileges mounting the host filesystem.  On Windows they will merely have unrestricted access to your user directory; on Linux it's trivial to use this to root the entire host.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but id like to get the non encrypted version to run before I start trying to get the secured version up on port 2376. I need to figure out why it crashes in the first place.